# Разные результаты у re.search и re.findall при одинаковом паттерне

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
import re

str = '''
139.255.50.180:8080 ID-N-S + 
88.99.83.28:3128 DE-H - 
96.118.254.95:8080 US-N +
''' 

pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d{1,}')

print(pattern.search(str)[0])
print(pattern.findall(str))
```

результат:

```
>>> 139.255.50.180:8080
>>> ['50.', '83.', '254.']
```

К .search претензий ноль, а что не нравится .findall - почему не дает три айпишника?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [73]: pattern = re.compile(r'(?:[0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d{1,}')
# NOTE: ---------------------->  ^^

In [74]: pattern.findall(str)
Out[74]: ['139.255.50.180:8080', '88.99.83.28:3128', '96.118.254.95:8080']
```

[цитата из официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> ...
>
> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group.
>
> ...

---

PS старайтесь не использовать в качестве имен переменных / классов зарезервированные имена, такие как [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), т.к. после этого вы не сможете использовать "затененные" функции / классы:

```
In [82]: str(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-5c73dd08b6cc> in <module>
----> 1 str(1)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```